# uniformly convergence of heat equation

Tags: analysis

**Problem**

> Let $u(x,t) = \frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{4t}}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} $ for $ t > 0,
> > x \in \mathbb{R} $. If a > 0, prove that $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t
> > \rightarrow 0+$, uniformly for $x \in [a, \infty ]$

I proved like this, but I didn't understand well.

> $|u(x,t)| \le u(a,t)$ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ and $u(a,t) =
>  \frac{e^\frac{-a^2}{4t}}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} $.
>  As t -> 0+, $e^\frac{-a^2}{4t}$
>   converges to zero much faster than $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} $ to
>   infinity. Thus u(a,t) uniformly converges to zero, so u(x,t) uniformly
>   converges to zero for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}
> $.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that $u(a,t) \to 0$ is equivalent to showing that $u^{2}(a,t) \to 0$. Make the substitution $s=\frac {a^{2}} {2t}$ and reduce to the proof to $se^{-s} \to 0$ as $ s\to \infty$ Apply L'Hopital's Rule to the ration $ \frac s {e^{s}}$.